# Hide fields from Odoo graph view

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I'm working on an **Odoo** *graph view*. An **SQL** view was needed to display all the fields in the graph view.

This is the python code:
from openerp import fields, models, tools, api

```
class omzettenperdag_sql_view(models.Model):
    _name = "omzettenperdag_sql_view"
    _auto = False

    #m2o fields to retrieve data from in SQL view query:
    account_invoice = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='account.invoice', readonly=True, invisible=True)
    account_invoice_line = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='account.invoice.line', readonly=True, invisible=True)

    #Fields returned from SQL view:
    hoeveelheid = fields.Float(string="Hoeveelheid")
    prijs_excl = fields.Float(string="Prijs excl. btw")
    datum = fields.Datetime(String="Datum")
    verkoopskanaal = fields.Char(string="Verkoopskanaal")

    #Create SQL view:
    def init(self, cr):
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, self._table)
        cr.execute("""
           #SQL view query here...
            );
           """)
```

This is the xml code of the *graph view*:

```
<record id="view_account_invoice_line_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">account.invoice.line.graph</field>
<field name="model">omzettenperdag_sql_view</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <graph string="Omzetten per dag" type="pivot">
        <field name="datum" type="row"/>
        <field name="verkoopskanaal" type="col"/>
        <field name="prijs_excl" type="measure"/>
        <field name="hoeveelheid" type="measure"/>
    </graph>
</field>
</record>
```

This works nicely:
[image]

I can split it further by date when I rightclick the month.
The issue is that it's also possible to choose the m2o fields (account_invoice and account_invoice_line). That makes no sense and ofcourse gives an error.

The fields have the invisible attribute set in the python code.

Is there any way to hide those 2 fields from that "right-click-menu"?
I don't want users to click there and get errors.

Comment: why not just remove them from the report ? the report is custom right ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the version 12 of odoo doc, you can simply hide a field this way:

```
<record id="view_account_invoice_line_graph" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">account.invoice.line.graph</field>
<field name="model">omzettenperdag_sql_view</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <graph string="Omzetten per dag" type="pivot">
        <field name="datum" type="row"/>
        <field name="verkoopskanaal" type="col"/>
        <field name="prijs_excl" type="measure"/>
        <field name="hoeveelheid" type="measure" />
        <field name="account_invoice" invisible="1" />
        <field name="account_invoice_line" invisible="1" />
    </graph>
</field>
</record>
```

Kind regards